# sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: deprecated in iOS7

Tags: uitableview, ios7, deprecated

I'm updating my app to iOS 7 and finally got it, but there's one thing I can't find a solution for.

In Xcode 4 I used the following method:

```
#define FONT_SIZE 14.0f
#define CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH 280.0f
#define CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN 10.0f


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {
    NSString *text = [textA objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 28.0f);

    return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);
}
```

But I'll get an error when using it in iOS 7:

> **Use -boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:**

I don't know how to convert my earlier version to this new method and it would be great if anyone could help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**sizeWithFont** methods were deprecated in iOS7. You should use **boundingRectWithSize** instead. If you also need to support prior iOS versions then you can use following code:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeZero;

if ([label.text respondsToSelector: @selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)] == YES) {
    size = [label.text boundingRectWithSize: constrainedSize options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                 attributes: @{ NSFontAttributeName: label.font } context: nil].size;
} else {
    size = [label.text sizeWithFont: label.font constrainedToSize: constrainedSize lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're only supporting ios6 and later, you can convert your `NSStrings` to `NSAttributedStrings` and use `NSAttributedString`'s `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:`.

Something that looked like this before:

```
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font
               constrainedToSize:(CGSize){maxWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX}];
```

Could be easily converted to this and work in both ios6 and ios7:

```
NSAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
        initWithString:text
        attributes:@
        {
            NSFontAttributeName:    font
        }];
CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){maxWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];
CGSize size = rect.size;
```

As a side note, the benefit of doing things this way is so your text sizing in ios6 is now thread-safe.  The old methods of `sizeWithFont:...` belonged to UIStringDrawing, which would crash if you ran `sizeWithFont:...` on two threads at the same time.  In ios6, new NSStringDrawing functions for `NSAttributedStrings` were exposed and the `boundingRectWithSize:...` function is thread safe.  I'm guessing this is why in ios7, the old `sizeWithFont:...` functions were deprecated.

Please note the documentation mentions:

> In iOS 7 and later, this method returns fractional sizes (in the size
>   component of the returned CGRect); to use a returned size to size
>   views, you must use raise its value to the nearest higher integer
>   using the ceil function.

So to pull out the calculated height or width to be used for sizing views, I would use:

```
CGFloat height = ceilf(size.height);
CGFloat width  = ceilf(size.width);
```

Answer (score 2):

sizeWithFont API you are using is deprecated on iOS7.

```
// See UIStringDrawing.h
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "Use -boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:"); // NSTextAlignment is not needed to determine size
```

You can use the API suggestion like so:

```
NSMutableDictionary *atts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[atts setObject:myFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

CGRect rect = [myText boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                              attributes:atts
                                 context:nil];
```