# How to specify NSLineBreakMode in boundingRectWithSize?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

```
 [text boundingRectWithSize:BOLIVIASize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:FONT} context:nil];
```

That is the new replacement for

```
- (CGSize) sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode) lineBreakMode
```

However, how do I specify the lineBreakMode parameter on boundingRectWithSize?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834275/sizewithfontconstrainedtosizelinebreakmode-deprecated-in-ios7

Answer (score 13):

use `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` & `NSParagraphStyle`:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraph.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping; //e.g.

CGSize size = [label.text boundingRectWithSize: constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes: @{ NSFontAttributeName: label.font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph } context: nil].size;
```