# sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:' is deprecated

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, deprecated

How do you correct this?

> 'sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0 - Use - boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:

```
float height = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(widthOfTextView, 999999.0f)
lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height + verticalPadding;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacement for deprecated -sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: in iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903304/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfontconstrainedtosizelinebreakmode-in-ios)

Comment: Please search before posting. Other duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673176/sizewithfontconstrainedtosizelinebreakmode-deprecated?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834275/sizewithfontconstrainedtosizelinebreakmode-deprecated-in-ios7?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922252/sizewithfontconstrainedtosizelinebreakmodeis-deprecated?rq=1

Comment: Yes, I have looked at these pages already.  I just don't know how to apply their solution to my code.

Comment: Every one of the referenced duplicates have answers that show how to call `boundingRectWithSize...`. They all show how to pass in the font and the constraining size. If you are having issues, update your question with your attempts to use `boundingRectWithSize...` and explain what issues you are having.

Answer (score 0):

As the warning says, use the `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` method instead.

Comment: Yes, but how would you rewrite it?  Just to replacing the text doesn't fix it.